# Before the form is displayed, all radio buttons belong to the same radio group

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have two groups of radio buttons, I need the first radio button in each group to be checked as default, but for some reason, after starting, only the last one that I checked is checked, and it does not matter if I do it from code or in the layout, after showing the form, the groups work correctly, but are not initialized correctly, here is an example and the result:

```
<StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="1.1" IsChecked="True"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="1" Content="1.2"/>
        </StackLayout>
        
        <StackLayout>
            <RadioButton GroupName="2" Content="2.1" IsChecked="True"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="2" Content="2.2"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

the result:

[image]

while expected result should be:

[image]

I tried changing the layout, grouping the radio buttons in different ways, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using a `RadioButtonGroup.GroupName` on the `StackLayout`s instead? According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/radiobutton#explicit-grouping-with-the-radiobuttongroupgroupname-attached-property) the `RadioButton.GroupName` should take precedence but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, I have tried RadioButtonGroup.GroupName, it makes no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project with your code and I can reproduce your problem in my project. But this problem only appeared on the windows platform. I can get the expected result when I tested it on the android.

In addition, I found it is a known issue on the github. You can follow up this issue about [RadioButton GroupName and IsChecked properties work inconsistently on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7595).

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'm sure it's not my fault.